# how to properly wrap C API in python using ctypes?

Tags: python, c, ctypes, word-wrap

I have wrapped two API's from a C library in Python using ctypes. One works and the other doesn't. My question is: how do I properly wrap API from from a C library in Python using ctypes?

some background info:

```
import ctypes 
from ctypes import *

MF = (b'path_to_file') 
beginTime = (-Value)
endTime = (Value)
PN = (b'path_to_String')
DT_RETURNGMT = 0x0100
DT_FLOAT = 0x0001
convert = DT_RETURNGMT|DT_FLOAT
```

This one works:

```
#read functions
dll.openFile.argtypes = c_char_p,
dll.openFile.restype = POINTER(File)

dll.freeFile.argtypes = POINTER(File),
dll.freeFile.restype = None
f = dll.openFile(MF)
print(f[0].fileInfo[0].items)
```

This one does not:

```
#retrieve data
dll.readSP.argtypes = POINTER(File), c_char_p(PN), 
c_double(beginTime), c_double(endTime),
0, 0, 
c_ushort(convert),
dll.readSP.restype = POINTER(SP)
#pointer to the SP file structure 
g = dll.readSP(f, MF)
print(g)
print(g[0].points)
pint(g[0].tStamp[0].data[0].TTag)
```

I think the pointer is correct because when I tell the code to print(g) it returns the location of my SP object like this:

```
<__main__.LP_SP object at 0x000001D1EAB862C8>
```

but it cant return the location of anything else in the SP file structure. Which leads me to believe it is how I wrapped the API that is the problem. But i'm not sure where I went wrong with it.

I think that I must not have wrapped the API correctly but i'm not sure where I went wrong.  double *refTIME, and struct TimeTage *refGMT are NULL in the C code so I have them as 0 in my script.

Comment: How is `File` defined?

Comment: What's with all those line breaks in the middle of what seems to be intended as one statement?

Comment: Or are they not intended to be one statement? Looking again, they don't make much sense as one statement, or as anything else, really. What is all that stuff between `dll.readSP.argtypes = POINTER(File), c_char_p(PN),` and `dll.readSP.restype = POINTER(SP)` supposed to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've defined *instances* instead of *types* in the non-working code. Instead of:

```
dll.readSP.argtypes = POINTER(File), c_char_p(PN), c_double(beginTime), c_double(endTime), 0, 0, c_ushort(convert),
```

You need:

```
dll.readSP.argtypes = POINTER(File), c_char_p, c_double, c_double, c_double, POINTER(TTag), c_ushort
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought that was the problem but I just wasn't sure. So your answer solved a problem I was having but now i'm getting an error when I call the dll. I'm getting a `TypeError this function takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)` this error occurs when I call the dll and the call looks like this `g = readSP(MF)` What exactly does it mean by arguments? @101

Comment: and file is defined like so(shortened for convenience): `class File(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
             ('name', ctypes.c_char_p),
             ('header', ctypes.POINTER(Header)),
             ('FInfo', ctypes.POINTER(FInfo)),`

Comment: Arguments are the values inside the function call brackets, e.g. `MF` is your first and only argument. It's expecting another. Do you have a link to the documentation for the DLL you're calling?